# GFCI outlet and breaker

Tags: wire

I recently bought a house. In the dinning room, the previous owners added a gfci outlet connected to a gfci breaker. What might they have used this for? I can’t seem to find any relevant case. Location is Lafayette, IN.

Comment: A GFCI breaker is mandatory in the USA for 'wet' areas such as the kitchen and bathrooms. There are no rules for using them in dry areas, unless the building is in a flood zone. Even then it is still at the owners discretion. Maybe just being cautious.

Comment: Note that UL standards are changing all the time. Arc Fault breakers are required now in some areas, especially old houses with aluminum wiring. Ten years from now a new house may need both types for the entire house.

Comment: Would they have been taking power outside - barbeque area lights? or for an electric lawnmower? In the UK, outside electric tools require the use of an ELCB (Earth leakage Circuit Breaker) - GFCI to Americans...

Comment: @SolarMike Don’t forget RCB.

Comment: @winny I didn’t, but the OP asked about his gfci ...

Comment: Check the trip setting on each. The dining room GFCI may provide some discrimination and trip at a lower ground fault current or faster than the main one. This would lessen the likelihood of the whole house being tripped.

Comment: Perhaps the previous owner was a "Spilly Willie".... Or maybe they were electronics hobbyists and used that room as their lab... who knows.

Comment: You have not specified where you live. NEC is USA originated but adopted in some other areas. In the USA, each state has its own electrical code and many states allow smaller contained jurisdictions to adopt their own codes. Some jurisdiction codes adopt the latest edition of NEC and only add the necessary enforcement rules etc. Others have their own additions and deletions to NEC items.

Comment: There really isn't any good reason to hang a GFCI outlet on a GFCI breaker. Whoever did that probably doesn't know what they're doing. The breaker protects the entire circuit, so you can safely replace the outlet with a 'plain' one if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a GFCI breaker no other GFCI device is needed and sometimes a second GFCI device can cause nuisance tripping. I have seen a DIY person that did not understand put close to 50 GFCI outlets in his home that only had 5 or 6 branch circuits and thought he had miswired because now he was constantly tripping them. So why was a GFCI outlet added to a GFCI protected branch circuit? Probably because the person did not understand how they work.

Comment: Makes sense, I could not understand why it was there and either the breaker or outlet would constantly trip